# Automaticly testing forms

Tags: php, web-applications, automated-tests

Hey, I've a application written with a MVC framework it has about 10 forms to insert new data or update existing data. Now every time i extend a feature i have to retest the hole application, and that takes time. how can i automate this? I don't have experience with this unit test thing and as far as i understood the concept its not that useful for me anyway, but maybe I'm wrong. so please adjust your answers to a beginner friendly level :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested by the [Selenium suite](http://seleniumhq.org/) : basically, it allows one to store tests as an HTML succession of "commands", and run them later in an automated *(or semi-automated, as you wish)* fashion, in a real browser.

And there is some component bundled in [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) *(the most used PHP automated testing framework)* to use Selenium -- see [Chapter 18. PHPUnit and Selenium](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/selenium.html)

Basically, you generally :

- Record the way you navigate in your application, using the firefox plugin called [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)
- Then, you often tune that scenario a bit -- generally, to make some stuff more dynamic, for instance
- And, finally, you run the scenarii through [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) *(Which is a "remote control" to a real browser)*, using PHPUnit classes

It allows you to run the same tests again and again, in a real browser -- which means really using your application.

A couple of notes :

- You obviously need a computer on which a browser can be launched (i.e. a testing server with some GUI)
- You sometimes/often have to adapt a bit your HTML templates, to add some `id`, or stuff like that
- The static scenarii recorded by Selenium IDE generally need to be made more "dynamic" -- an example being that, because of a UNIQUE constraint in your DB, you can't use the same e-mail address twice to register two different users : the address needs to be dynamic
- Running tests with Selenium takes time : each page has to be loaded in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into selenium (seleniumhq.org). There are a whole bucketload of apps that do this kind of thing... this one so happens to be a favorite.

It basically records your keystrokes/click and allows you to replay them. Best of all, it has a firefox extension- which makes this far too easy.